# If a mega on-line company ships you two of an item when you ordered one and charges you for one, are you obligated to notify them of the error?

Tags: halacha, internet, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, mistakes

Let's say you place an order for three items A, B, and C. You order quantity one of each, but get two of item B, because the company shipped from multiple warehouses (i.e., shipped two of the item by accident). You did not get charged for the extra item B, whose value is say $400.

Are you obligated to inform the company of their error and return the extra item B?

Some additional circumstancial info: We are dealing with a large internet sales company here and not a fellow Jew. Also, it is not a Jewish owned company.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82780/discussion-between-b-a-and-donielf).